# What is effect in context of Redux-Saga

Tags: redux-saga

According to the [doc](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/DeclarativeEffects.html):

> we yield plain JavaScript Objects from the Generator. We call those Objects Effects.

it seems to be a JavaScript object looking e.g. like this:

```js
// Effect -> call the function Api.fetch with `./products` as argument
{
  CALL: {
    fn: Api.fetch,
    args: ['./products']
  }
}
```

It seems to be a result of one of [effect creators](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#effect-creators).

However documentation to [`all([...effects])`](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#alleffects---parallel-effects) looks like accepted parameters are effects and at he same time `all()` function accepts promises and generators as well.

```js
import { all, call } from 'redux-saga/effects'

const callEffect = call(console.log, 'foo')

function* gen() {
    console.log('bar')
}

const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log('baz')
    resolve()
})

function* print() {
    yield all([ callEffect, gen(), promise])
}
```

Calling `print()` saga will result in `foo`, `bar` and `baz` being printed.

What actually is an effect? Array of what type is parameter of `all([...effects])` function?

Comment: When talking about effects in redux-saga you can mean either just the effect objects or anything that the redux-saga corutine can handle. Although generally I think people will mean the former. I think the type of the 'array' can be only described by 'what the authors decided to support` which can be found in redux-saga api reference. If you are interested in deeper understanding of effects in programming I recommend watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z8SI7WBtlcA.

Answer (score 1):

An Effect in redux-saga is a simple object describing a [side effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29). The idea is, instead of directly executing the "effect" (which could be a regular function call, or a `put`, or a `select`, etc), you yield an Effect object describing the operation to redux-saga, and the library decides what to do with it (which, in the case of `call`, will just execute your function). The rationale for this is that it hypothetically makes testing easier, because you can run a saga as a normal generator and just compare the objects yielded, without having to mock anything.

The fact that Effects, Promises, and generators are mostly interchangeable in redux-saga is just a convenience feature of the library. Promises and generators are not themselves Effects, but they are used often enough in redux-saga code that the author saw benefit in supporting them as first-class citizens. For instance, `yield`ing a Promise will block until the promise resolves, and doing `yield call` on a function that returns a Promise will do the same. This has nothing to do with effects, though, so the documentation is a bit misleading here. (If you look at [the TypeScript definition for `all`](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/packages/core/effects.d.ts#L112-L113), you can see that there is actually a generic version of it that takes parameters of any type, not just Effects.)